# What is the advantage of .desktop files without executable bit set?

Tags: files, permissions, x11, security, .desktop

The [freedesktop](https://www.freedesktop.org) organization [defines the standard](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) for `.desktop` files. Unfortunately it defines not the **permissions** of the file (see [freedesktop mailinglist](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2017-June/thread.html#13920)) and software is distributed with

```
a) executable .desktop files
b) non executable .desktop files
c) mixed a) and b) in one software package.
```

This is not very satisfying for [Linux distributors](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/.desktop_files), who aim to provide a consistent system. I want to use the broad audience of sx, to find out

**what advantage has a .desktop file *without* execution bit?** Is there any reason for not having all `.desktop` files executable if the filesystem alows it?

Are there known security problems? Are there programs which have difficulties with executable `.desktop` files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One obvious reason a `.desktop` has not necessarily the executable bit set is these files were not intended to be executable in the first place. A `.desktop` file contains metadata the tell the desktop environment how to associate programs to file types but was never designed to be executed itself.

However, as a `.desktop` file indirectly tell the graphic environment what to execute, it has an indirect capacity to launch whatever program is defined in it, opening the door to exploits. To avoid malicious `.desktop` files to be responsible to the launch of hostile or unwanted programs, KDE and gnome developers introduced a custom hack that somewhat deviates the intended Unix file execution permission purpose to add a security layer. With this new layer, only `.desktop` files with the executable bit set are taken into account by the desktop environment.

Just turning a non executable file like a `.desktop` one to an executable one would be a questionable practice because it introduces a risk. Non binary executable files with no shebang are executed by a shell (be it `bash` or `sh` or whatever). Asking the shell to execute a file which is not a shell script has unpredictable results.

To avoid that issue, a shebang needs to be present in the `.desktop` files and should point to the right command designed to handle them, [xdg-open](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-open.html), like for example Thunderbird does here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Thunderbird
GenericName=Email
Comment=Send and Receive Email
...
```

In this case, executing the `.desktop` file will do whatever `xdg-open` (and your Desktop Environment) believe is the right thing to do, possibly just opening the file with a browser or a text editor which might not be what you expect.

Comment: That's rather the result of a longer debate [as I pointed out here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294952/should-usr-bin-env-xdg-open-be-included-in-desktop-files#comment517347_294952) (btw, the accepted answer to that question is utterly wrong...) and it is also implemented in GNOME (and possibly other DEs but I wouldn't know). However, these "security measures" (i.e. shebang and _chmod+x_) do not apply to desktop files that come from upstream and are placed in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` only to local files placed in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications`

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks for the information, answer adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

## Security considerations of type 1 desktop files

Desktop files are textual configuration files
that are used by file managers and window managers.
As noted above, their format is
[specified by a FreeDesktop standard](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.5/):

> Both the KDE and GNOME desktop environments have adopted a similar format for
> "desktop entries", or configuration files describing how a particular program
> is to be launched, how it appears in menus, etc. It is to the larger
> community's benefit that a unified standard be agreed upon by all parties
> such that interoperation between the two environments, and indeed any
> additional environments that implement the specification, becomes simpler.

The [current FreeDesktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html)
lists three different kinds of desktop entries:

> This specification defines 3 types of desktop entries: `Application` (type
> 1), `Link` (type 2) and `Directory` (type 3). To allow the addition of new
> types in the future, implementations should ignore desktop entries with an
> unknown type.

The security implications of `Application` (type 1) desktop files
have been discussed at length multiple times on the FreeDesktop mailing list:

> I noticed quite a while ago that .desktop files as specified by
> freedesktop.org open a window into GNU/Linux for a whole range of
> viruses and trojans.  I think that this has been discussed
> before.  I see that the issue has not been resolved so I'd like to
> suggest a way to resolve it.
>
> Conventionally files downloaded from the Internet cannot simply be
> "clicked" to run them under unix/GNU/Linux, the execute permission must
> be granted (or an installer used or archive extracted).

--- Sam Watkins,
"[.desktop files, serious security hole, virus-friendliness](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2006-April/006357.html)",
April 2006
([LWN summary](https://lwn.net/Articles/178409/))

> In the event that the launch would have been forbidden based on the preceding
> restrictions, the user is given the option of automatically making the service
> executable and then launching.  Although this part makes me a bit queasy I
> think it's the best option to easily allow existing Desktop icons, panel
> launchers, etc. to continue to work.

--- Michael Pyne,
"[.desktop file security](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2009-February/010209.html)",
February 2009

To the best of my knowledge,
there is only one CVE associated with desktop files:
[CVE-2017-14604](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-14604).

> GNOME Nautilus before 3.23.90 allows attackers to spoof a file type by using
> the .desktop file extension, as demonstrated by an attack in which a .desktop
> file's Name field ends in .pdf but this file's Exec field launches a
> malicious "sh -c" command. In other words, Nautilus provides no UI indication
> that a file actually has the potentially unsafe .desktop extension; instead,
> the UI only shows the .pdf extension. One (slightly) mitigating factor is
> that an attack requires the .desktop file to have execute permission. The
> solution is to ask the user to confirm that the file is supposed to be
> treated as a .desktop file, and then remember the user's answer in the
> metadata::trusted field.

There's more background here if you're curious:

> nautilus: CVE-2017-14604: .desktop files can hide malware in Nautilus
>
> There is a bug in Nautilus that makes it possible to disguise a
> malicious script as an innocent document, like a PDF or ODT, that gets
> executed when the user opens it.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860268

> The exploit I created is a file called `sgos_handbook.pdf.desktop` (though I
> could have named it `malware.desktop` and it would have looked the same in
> Nautilus). Here’s what’s inside of it. Note that the name is set to
> `sgos_handbook.pdf`, and the icon is `gnome-mime-application-pdf` which is
> the default icon for PDFs in Subgraph — these two things make it so you can’t
> tell that this isn’t a PDF when viewing it in Nautilus.

https://micahflee.com/2017/04/breaking-the-security-model-of-subgraph-os/

Here's a simplified version of the proof-of-concept malicious desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=my-file.pdf
Exec=sh -c "xeyes"
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-mime-application-pdf
```

The icon looks like a PDF file,
but rather than opening a PDF file,
it runs a shell script that runs `xeyes`.
Of course, `xeyes` could just as easily be `rm -rf $HOME`
or something similarly malicious.
This has since been fixed
by requiring the user to actively trust the desktop file
before the file manager displays the custom icon and name.

## Other purposes of desktop files.

However, desktop files are used for more than
associating mimetypes and launching applications.

Let's start with type 3,
which are desktop entries
but are `.directory` files,
not exactly `.desktop` files.

### Directory files (type 3)

Directory files (type 3) are mainly used for creating categories
in hierarchical menus; that's what the `Categories`
key is for in type 1 desktop files.
For example, consider this example
from `/usr/share/desktop-directories/Utility.directory`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Accessories
Comment=Desktop accessories
Icon=applications-utilities
Type=Directory
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-menus-3.0
```

So if a desktop file has "Utility" in its `Categories` key,
it will show up in the `Utility` menu subdirectory.

The Dolphin file manager also uses directory files
to e.g. [enable/disable thumbnail previews of images](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=150923).

As far as I know,
there is no reason for `.directory` files to be executable.

### Link-type desktop files (type 2)

Link-type desktop files can point to arbitrary URLs.
This makes it easy to store
relevant links or URL in a given directory.

Currently, most file managers require link-type desktop files to be executable
before opening the URL.
This makes sense,
because although opening a URL is not equivalent to running arbitrary code,
`file://` URLs can point to executables,
and URLs in general can be malicious.

#### file URLs

For example, in Ubuntu the `example-content` package
adds a type 2 desktop file
similar to this in the home directory:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Examples
Comment=Example content for Ubuntu
URL=file:///usr/share/example-content/
Icon=folder
```

Double-clicking on this desktop file in a file manager
will navigate to the `/usr/share/example-content/` folder.

Link-type desktop files [can also point to files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310618/is-it-possible-to-create-a-soft-link-on-my-desktop-which-opens-with-the-target-p).
For example, here's one that opens the manual for the LaTeX `hyperref` package:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=hyperref manual
URL=file:///usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf
```

#### http/https URLs

Link-type desktop files can also be used to open HTTP URLs in the browser.
For example, here is a desktop file linking to this page:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=What is the advantage of .desktop files without executable bit set?
Type=Link
URL=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373239/what-is-the-advantage-of-desktop-files-without-executable-bit-set
```

This isn't the most cross-platform option,
but it is
[widely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12170/create-url-link-in-menu)
[used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151004/how-do-i-get-a-desktop-in-kde-to-open-a-new-browser-window).

#### other URLs

Link-type desktop files can contain arbitrary URLs;
as long as there is a handler registered for the URI scheme,
they will work.
For example, a desktop file could contain a `mailto:` URL:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Email Linus Torvalds
Type=Link
URL=mailto:torvalds@transmeta.com
```

or an `smb://` URL:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Samba share
Type=Link
URL=smb://username@server/my-samba-share
```

or a special file-manager URL like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Trash
Type=Link
Icon=user-trash-full
EmptyIcon=user-trash
URL=trash:///
```

or this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Recent documents
Type=Link
Icon=document-open-recent
URL=recent:///
```

## Related links.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/687236/why-do-we-have-desktop-files
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/2484/what-does-examples-desktop-do
- [fully disable the .desktop file function under GNOME?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12713/fully-disable-the-desktop-file-function-under-gnome)